# The request method type is not supported: OPTIONS in ATG

Tags: weblogic12c, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

Im having a issue while making a API Call with Request Method POST. The preflight OPTIONS method is failing. I'm running ATG on weblogic 12c. The following is my CORS Code

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import atg.servlet.*;
import atg.servlet.pipeline.*;

public class CORSHeaderServlet extends InsertableServletImpl{
  public CORSHeaderServlet () {}
  public void service (DynamoHttpServletRequest request,
                       DynamoHttpServletResponse response)
       throws IOException, ServletException
  {
     //add headers to response.
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ,"*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-PINGOTHER");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86000");
    passRequest (request, response);
  }
}
```

The Browser error is

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7003/rest/model/atg/userprofiling/ProfileActor/login' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status
```

The Java Error is

```
 ]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.servlet.ServletException: The request method type is not supported: OPTIONS
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.serviceRESTRequest(RestPipelineServlet.java:493)
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:274)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:320)
        at atg.rest.servlet.RestPipelineServlet.service(RestPipelineServlet.java:278)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Comment: No that particular thread is deals with CORS in NodeJS my question is very specific to Oracle ATG

Comment: Your issue is the same

Comment: Yea issue is the same but none of those solutions are working for me so I thought of posting the question hoping to get a ATG specific solution

Answer (score 0):

The `RestPipelineServlet` is supposed to pass the request off to the correct `RestProcessor`. Looking at the `RestProcessor` interface it appears it only implements a subset of the `METHODS` you want to use ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/apidoc/atg/rest/processor/RestProcessor.html)). So for your solution you'll probably have to implement a `doRESTOptions` method in the `ActorProcessor` and work from there.

It will not be trivial to get this injected into the application. There may also be available `METHOD` validation on the implemented methods in the `RestPipelineServlet` that you need to look into and override/extend.